# JavaFX loader isn't loading my FXML file properly

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, netbeans

JavaFX loader is giving me this error: 
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

The FXML file is in the same package so it should be able to locate it.

```
public class Main extends Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
          launch(args);
   }

 @Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
      Parent panel;
       try {
           panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginPage.fxml"));
                 Scene scene = new Scene(panel);
                 primaryStage.setTitle("MENU");
                 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
                 primaryStage.show();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
Please add the **complete error message**.

Comment: Since every exception is wrapped in a `InvocationTargetException`, this question type alone provides little information. The causes contain the really important info. Also note that we'll need additional info to identify the issue: Classpath structure, fxml file and controller could depending on the error all contain information required to identify the exact issue...

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full stack trace of the exception you’re getting, including all `Caused by:` sections.  That stack trace tells you what went wrong, where, and why.

Comment: I don't know how you are setting "panel = FXMLLoader" What ide are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you miss something in the controller of loginPage.fxml.
If you set fx:Id for any node in your fxml file but you didn't use it in the controller file, then thats the problem due to which it gives you that error.
Check out your controller file.